# Is it possible to enable rails' built in CSRF protection on a GET action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csrf

I understand why rails defaults to disabling CSRF protection on GET requests, but I have an edgecase where this is required. Is there a way to do this in rails?

Answer (score -2):

I think you can do it in the following way in your controller.

```
class FooController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery
end
```